# How to fix console error in Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm newbie in Unity & I wanted to add a water to my scene but the water that I added looks purple and I got two error messages as well in my console which says:

Material Does Not Have A Color Property

So how to fix this issue ? There must be a problem with my shader texture however the material has the write texture.. Print Screens Are Below:

[image]

Comment: you are missing material of some object. click on purple thingy and check inspector and you will see where to apply material :)

Answer (score 0):

That's the graphics card's way of telling you it doesn't know which shader to apply your object.

Click on a mesh that is pink, and the material property will be set to none or missing. You'll need to remap the materials in your project to your pink objects, or drag the textures back onto your objects again.

Answer (score 0):

### You are seeing this pink color because a shader is **missing or** is not **properly selected.**

I'm sure the following is the error you'd encounter in the inspector:
[image]

### This is how it should look if everything is correct:

*`I selected the shader in the file browser so you can check the location yourself.`*
[image: Correct shader]

### Resolving the issue

- The first thing you could try to resolve this issue is open the shader tab in the inspector and search the "Shader" dropdown menu for the water shader:
  [image: Select the shader]
- If you can't find it there the only option is to reimport the assetpack.
- Or copy this shader from another project where you still have it.